# Editing PHP files Using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am using the following script to edit text based files on my server (TXT,HTML,PHP,etc..)

```
<?php
    $filename = "test.php";

    function make_content_file($filename,$content,$opentype="w")
    {
        $fp_file = fopen($filename, $opentype);
        fputs($fp_file, $content);
        fclose($fp_file);
    }

    if($_POST)
    {
         $newcontents=$_POST[newcontents];
         make_content_file($filename,$newcontents);
    }
    $filecontents = file_get_contents($filename);
?>

<?php
    if($_POST)
    {
        echo '<p><span style="font-weight: 700; background-color: #CCFFCC">You have successfully posted to your txt file!</span></p>
        <a href="".$filename."">Download</a>';
    }
?>

<form method="post">
    <textarea name="newcontents" cols="70" rows="25"><?=$filecontents?></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">  
</form>
```

The script works fine with most of PHP files Example:[image]

But if a file includes some form with textarea the code just get messed up

Example: [image]

Another Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZGVg.png

Would like to know why this happen and how to fix it, Thanks

Comment: `<?=htmlspecialchars($filecontents)?>`

Comment: Dont use short_open_tags, they are off by default on most servers. If you encode the chars, don't forget to decode them later when using them. And care whom you allow to edit files this way... for security's sake.

Comment: it happens because the browser will interpret the html, and you can't nest textareas.

Comment: @MarkBaker it is `<?=htmlspecialchars($filecontents)?>` not `html_special_chars` and it solved the issue, thank you. Maybe you want to answer it so i can accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

The first comment sums it all

Fun fact: I have a similar tool myself, with the ability to edit files from a **bookmark**, an **emptying files** feature, and sha1 **password protection.** (insecure crc32 is still used in the original code)

Hope it's actually useful

```php
if (sha1($_POST['pass']) != $pass) {
    echo "<style>input{padding:0.1em; font-size:1.1em}body{background:$bg; color:$fg; font-family:corbel;font-size:1.4vw;padding:0.4em}a{color:$fg}</style><body><h2>$nick<mark>:)</mark></h2>";
    echo '
        <form action="writer.php" method="post">
        Code: <input type="password" name="pass" autofocus>
        <input type="hidden" name="f" value="'.$_GET['f'].'"><br><br>';

    if ($_POST['pass'] != ""){
        echo 'Incorrect code.';
    }
}
```

https://pastebin.com/krMrA783

To empty a file, type "empty".
To set the password before using, go through the first 5 lines of code, and modify `$pass`.
Make sure that the password is secure and unique (14+ characters)